# How can I dynamically change the opacity of the main window in a WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, opacity

I'm having trouble figuring out how I can change the opacity of the main window of my WPF application during runtime. I managed to figure out how to change the background color of the main window by dynamically creating a new SolidColorBrush, but I can't seem to do anything similar for the opacity since it gets assigned a value between 0 and 1. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Opacity is a float between 0 and 1. On a related note, is AllowTransparency set to true?

Comment: No, it is currently set to false.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to true and using a DoubleAnimation?

Comment: Why don't you just bind the `scA` or `alphaValue` value in the XAML to a value in your ViewModel? Its like WPF 101. Just make sure you don't `freeze` your solid brush. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush(v=vs.110).aspx